# Finding the indices of the minimum in each 2D array from a 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, sub-array

I'm new to numpy and python in general and I am looking to find the minimum of each 2D subarray, given a 3D array. For example:

```
# construct an example 3D array
a = np.array([[5,4,1,5], [0,1,2,3], [3,2,8,1]]).astype(np.float32)
b = np.array([[3,2,9,3], [8,6,5,3], [6,7,2,8]]).astype(np.float32)
c = np.array([[9,7,6,5], [4,7,6,3], [1,2,3,4]]).astype(np.float32)
d = np.array([[5,4,9,2], [4,2,6,1], [7,5,9,1]]).astype(np.float32)
e = np.array([[4,5,2,9], [7,1,5,8], [0,2,6,4]]).astype(np.float32)

a = np.insert(a, 0, [np.inf]*len(a), axis=1)
b = np.insert(b, 1, [np.inf]*len(b), axis=1)
c = np.insert(c, 2, [np.inf]*len(c), axis=1)
d = np.insert(d, 3, [np.inf]*len(d), axis=1)
e = np.insert(e, 4, [np.inf]*len(e), axis=1)

arr = np.swapaxes(np.dstack((a,b,c,d,e)), 1, 2)
print(arr)
```

gives this result:
[3D Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBK26.png)

The result I'm looking for are the indices of the minimum element from each of the 2D arrays, something like:

```
[[0, 0, 3], # corresponding to the coordinates of element with value 1 in the first 2D array
 [1, 0, 1], # corresponding to the coordinates of element with value 0 in the second 2D array
 [2, 4, 0]] # corresponding to the coordinates of element with value 0 in the third 2D array
```

or something similar along those lines. I plan on using the indices to get that value, then replace the column and row in that 2D subarray with infinite values to find a next minimum that isn't in the same row/column.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [716]: arr
Out[716]: 
array([[[inf,  5.,  4.,  1.,  5.],
        [ 3., inf,  2.,  9.,  3.],
        [ 9.,  7., inf,  6.,  5.],
        [ 5.,  4.,  9., inf,  2.],
        [ 4.,  5.,  2.,  9., inf]],

       [[inf,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
        [ 8., inf,  6.,  5.,  3.],
        [ 4.,  7., inf,  6.,  3.],
        [ 4.,  2.,  6., inf,  1.],
        [ 7.,  1.,  5.,  8., inf]],

       [[inf,  3.,  2.,  8.,  1.],
        [ 6., inf,  7.,  2.,  8.],
        [ 1.,  2., inf,  3.,  4.],
        [ 7.,  5.,  9., inf,  1.],
        [ 0.,  2.,  6.,  4., inf]]], dtype=float32)
```

Reshape it to 2d:

```
In [717]: idx = np.argmin(arr.reshape(3,-1),1)
In [718]: idx
Out[718]: array([ 3,  1, 20])
```

Convert those indices to 2d:

```
In [719]: np.unravel_index(idx,(5,5))
Out[719]: (array([0, 0, 4]), array([3, 1, 0]))
```

this can then be further processed to get the values you  want - transpose and adding [0,1,2]

```
In [720]: np.transpose(np.vstack((np.arange(3),_)))
Out[720]: 
array([[0, 0, 3],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [2, 4, 0]])
```

Comment: Ah I was missing the `np.unravel_index`. Thank you for the help!